# Java Regex, match pattern, pair of words

Tags: java, regex

i am using regex to check correctness of the string in my application. I want to check if string has a following pattern: x=y&a=b&... x,y,a,b etc. can be empty.

Example of correct strings:

```
abc=def&gef=cda&pdf=cdf
=&gef=def
abc=&gef=def
=abc&gef=def
```

Example of incorrect strings:

```
abc=def&gef=cda&
abc=def&gef==cda&
abc=defgef=cda&abc=gda
```

This is my code showing current solution:

```
    String pattern = "[[a-zA-Z0-9]*[=]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*[&]{1}]*";
    if(!Pattern.matches(pattern, s)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
    }
```

This solution is bad because it accepts strings like:

```
abc=def&gef=def&
```

Can anyone help me with correct pattern?

Comment: No, string is containing only letters + numbers or is empty

Comment: =&= would be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:&[a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQmGhV/2)

When used with `matches()`, the `^` and `$` anchors may be omitted.

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumeric chars (may be replaced with `\p{Alnum}`)
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching sequences of...

  - `&` - a `&` symbol
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*`  - same as above
- `)*` - ... zero or more occurrences
- `$` - end of string

**NOTE**: If you want to make the pattern more generic, you may match any char other than `=` and `&` with a `[^&=]` pattern that would replace a more restrictive `[a-zA-Z0-9]` pattern:

```
^[^=&]*=[^=&]*(?:&[^=&]*=[^=&]*)*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQmGhV/3)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
^\w*=\w*(?:&(?:\w*=\w*))*$
```

- `^` is the starting anchor
- `(\w*=\w*)` is to represent parameters like `abc=def`

  - `\w` matches a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
  - `\w*` represents 0 or more characters
- `&` represents tha actual ampersand literal
- `(&(\w*=\w*))*` matches any subsequents parameters like `&b=d` etc.
- `$` represents the ending anchor

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/byPWwc/2)

**EDIT:** Made all groups non-capturing.

**Note:** As @WiktorStribiżew has pointed out in the comments, `\w` will match `_` as well, so above regex should be modified to exclude underscores if they are to be avoided in the pattern, i.e `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: `\w` also matches `_` symbols.

Comment: Valid point @WiktorStribiżew, would have to change all `\w` to `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want this.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*&)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*=[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

This matches any number of repetitions like `x=y`, with a `&` after each one; followed by one repetition like `x=y` without the following `&`.

Comment: Quantifying the pattern start causes more redundant backtracking than when quantifying the pattern end.